# Blow-up at locally closed center

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, blow-ups

Let $X$ be a scheme, and $Z\subset X$ is a locally closed subscheme. I am wondering that is there a reasonable definition of blow-up of $X$ at $Z$?

And of course, this blow-up $Bl_Z X$ should satisfy some usual properties. For example, as the universal property of original blow up, I expect if $f: Y\to X$ is a morphism such that $f^{-1}(Z)\to Y$ is a locally closed regular embedding of codimension one, then $f$ factor through the blow-up morphism $Bl_Z Y\to X$.

I think one possible way to define $Bl_Z X$ is that we can choose a decomposition $Z\to_{i} U\to_{j} X$ where $i$ is a closed embedding and $j$ an open embedding. Then I think it may be possible to glue $Bl_Z U$ and $X$ in a suitable way, and obtain $Bl_Z X$.

Are these kinds of things already constructed? I am wondering that if there is a reference.

Comment: You could blow up the closure of Z…

Comment: You can blow up along *any* map of derived schemes, obtaining a derived Artin stack. A reference (for the quasi-lci case): Khan–Rydh, *Virtual Cartier divisors and blow-ups*.

Comment: @Z.M what does their construction give for a locally closed immersion? Is the result still stacky/derived?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger It does not seem to be a scheme even when you look at something like $R\to R[f^{-1}]$. It is a derived algebraic space when the map is quasi-lci finite and unramified (Thm 5.3.3). I guess that, for good enough open immersions, it is a classical algebraic space.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger On the "derived" direction, for lci maps of schemes, nothing is really derived. I guess that this extends to quasi-lci maps. An analogue appears in Bhatt–Lurie, where the derived prismatization = prismatization under quasi-lciness.

Comment: @Z.M Thanks! But it seems that in that paper, the morphism is assumed to be quasi-lci, unramified and finite in Section 5? Does their construction work for any quasi-lci morphism between derived Artin stacks?

Comment: Oh, sorry, the paper that I referred to was only about a special case. A version for lci maps is sketched in Khan, *Virtual fundamental classes of derived stacks I*, §1.4. See also Khan, *Absolute Poincaré duality in étale cohomology*, Thm 2. The full version (for any map) seems to be in progress.

Comment: @Z.M it seems to me those references discuss deformation to the normal cone of an arbitrary lci morphism rather than blowups. If I understand the diagram of Thm 2 in the second paper correctly, in the case $X \subset Y$ is an lci locally closed embedding of classical schemes, then $D$ is like $Bl_{\bar{X} \times 0}(Y \times \mathbb{A}^1) \setminus (\hat{Y} \cup \pi^{-1}(\partial X \times 0))$ where $\bar{X}$ is the closure of $X$, $\partial X = \bar{X} \setminus X$, $\pi$ is the blowup map and $\hat{Y}$ is the strict transform of $Y \times 0$.

Comment: The point of $\textit{loc. cit.}$ seems to be to get around having to use blowups at all to construct the deformation to the normal cone $D$, and at least I don't see a reasonable definition of blowup (other than blowing up the closure) even using the derived machinery without the finite assumption of Khan-Rydh (which is used to reduce it to the case of a closed embedding). Am I missing something?

Comment: @DoriBejleri The appearance of Weil restriction is, in my opinion, not essential, but making the definition concise. The defining property of blowup (of $f\colon X\to Y$) is that it classifies virtual Cartier divisors over $f$. The prismatization (in Bhatt–Lurie) classifies Cartier–Witt divisors, and described in terms of functor of points which does not seem to admit a description in terms of Weil restriction.

Comment: @DoriBejleri (corrected to clarify the authors of the forthcoming paper) They are not quite different. Blowup contains an extra $\mathbb G_m$-equivariant structure than deformation to normal cone. In Thm 2, it suffices to replace the Weil restriction of $f$ along $0$ by that of $f\times B\mathbb G_m$ along $0\colon Y\times B\mathbb G_m\to Y\times[\mathbb A^1/\mathbb G_m]$. This would appear in the work by Hekking–Khan–Rydh (cited as [HKR]) in progress there.